# Can not login to bluemix using cf command line tool, cf fails with 404 error

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am trying to login to `bluemix` to push my app using `cf` command line too, but unable to login. My user name and password is correct. I can login using `Internet Explorer` on same url using same credentials and then trying cf from command prompt on my `Windows 7` system.

```
C:\Users>cf api https://ace.ng.bluemix.net
```

> Setting api endpoint to https://ace.ng.bluemix.net...
>
> FAILED
>
> Server error, status code: 404, error code: 0, message:

```
C:\Users>
```

Answer (score 1):

After contacting my colleague, I am able to correct the issue. Actually, we need to login to https://ace.ng.bluemix.net using internet explorer, but on command prompt, we need to run 'cf api https://api.ng.bluemix.net'. i.e. replaced 'ace' with 'api' in the url on command prompt. Then ran 'cf login' and use your email id and password to login. It worked fine. Now, we can run any other cf command.

Hope, it will help others facing similar issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you would want to do is the following.

`cf login -a https://api.ng.bluemix.net`

Answer (score 0):

The cf endpoint you need to target with the cf command line tool is https://api.ng.bluemix.net